# I get "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR" using mysql alias

Tags: javascript, sql

I want to create columns on the fly in the database.

But when I use SQL alias, I get back Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'product_sales' in 'field list.

The column product_sales is not recognized.

Here is my code:

```
let query = `SELECT dept_id, dept_name, over_head_costs, product_sales) AS product_sales, product_sales - over_head_costs AS profit FROM departments`;

connection.query(query, (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(res);
```

I expect the output to include all the column names including those which were created on the fly.

Comment: Creating columns "on the fly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong  closing `)` after product_sales try remove it

You are using `product_sales - over_head_costs` but juts before this columns you reassign the product_sales  using an alias (with the same name)  so you can't use alias in select clause  .. the you should remove the (unuseful ) aliasing for product_sales AS product_sales

```
let query = `SELECT dept_id, dept_name, over_head_costs
      , product_sales
      , product_sales - over_head_costs AS profit FROM departments`;
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I took out the ) and it still returns "Unknown column.. in the field list".